How to to loop through portion of Array in Swift
I want to loop through a portion of an Array in Swift, not the entire array based on the index. The array is coming from an API so I don't know the number of elements in advance.
For example for the array ["Joe's pizza","Sal's Pizza","Pizza Hut"], I would only like to loop through up to the first three (if there three) and then stop.  In some cases, the starting array will have less than 3 elements and in other cases more then 3 depending on what the API returns.
My code as follows does not work.
let myArray = ["Joe's","Sal's","Pizza Hut","Domino's","John's","Pizza King"]//from API. Could be more or less
let numElements = myArray.count
if numElements = 0 {
    print("none found")
    return
}
var i = 0
var str = ""
while i <= 2 {
    for i in 1...numElements-1 {
        print(i)
        str = myArray[i]
        print(str)
    }//end for loop
    i+=1
} // end while loop

The code will print the full 6 and not respect the while condition. If I put the while inside the for loop, it will needlessly go through the whole Array which could be quite long even though I only want up to the first 3
How can I limit the range used in the index (when I don't know if the actual array count is less than or greater than the number I'm seeking.
Thanks for any suggestions.

You can use the prefix() method for this since it returns up to the given number of elements from the beginning of the array.
for element in myArray.prefix(3) {
    print(element)
}


Thx! This also seems to be safe for the number of elements being less than 3
